# How to Delete a Mongodb collection using collection name in c#

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0

I have created a collection in a database using mongo in c# . Iam able to delete the content in the collection using ID but not the collection .Pls help me how to drop a collection using c#

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's not much to it, just call `Drop()` on the collection:

```
var test = db.GetCollection("test");
test.Drop();
```

**Update**: The new C# API way of doing this is:

```
db.DropCollection("test");
```